# (Java) need help finding 20 greatest and 20 smallest numbers

Tags: java

I've already found all of the numbers from 1- 9876543210 that are divisible by 1-10 through the for and if statements but I can't seem to figure out how to find the largest and the smallest numbers. Please if you do help me, explain how you did it and the logic behind it.

```
    long bignumber = 9876543210L; 
    for (int i = 0; i < bignumber; i++) {

        if (i % 1 == 0) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                if (i % 3 == 0) {
                    if (i % 4 == 0) {
                        if (i % 5 == 0) {
                            if (i % 6 == 0) {
                                if (i % 7 == 0) {
                                    if (i % 8 == 0) {
                                        if (i % 9 == 0) {

                                            }

                                        }
                                        else {

                                        }
                                    }
                                    else {

                                    }
                                }
                                else {

                                }
                            }
                            else {

                            }
                        }
                        else {

                        }
                    }
                    else {

                    }
                }
                else {

                }
            }
            else {

            }
        }
        else {

        }

    }
```

Comment: :O This is _horrible_. What do you want to do here?

Comment: i need to find the greatest and smallest numbers of the ones filtered out from the if statements.

Comment: `i` should be a `long` otherwise it's an infinite loop.

Comment: @PaulBoddington oh thank you

Comment: Just an FYI, there are a lot more efficient approaches to this than filtering.  You are basically trying to find common multiples to 1...10 (and hint: since all numbers divisible by 6-10 are already divisible by 1-5, you don't care about 1-5 either).  There are ways to compute this directly, involving first finding the Least Common Multiple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to write your code for you, but here are some hints.

Firstly, `i` should be of type `long` because otherwise it's an infinite loop. Every `int` value is less than `9876543210L`. That's why you used `long` in the first place.

Secondly, I recommend learning about the `&&` operator. This can be used instead of nested `if` statements.

Thirdly, if you only need the 20 smallest values and the 20 largest, you could use 2 loops. The first should loop through the numbers in ascending order and `break` when 20 values have been found. The second should loop through the values in descending order and `break` when 20 have been found.

Comment: sorry to bother you again but im still having trouble with just making the for loops loop through only 20 values, but i found out how to use &&.

Comment: oh ok i see thank you i don't think i could have ever figured this out, so thank you once again.

Comment: oh i figured it out sorry for bothering you ( i deleted my earlier comment about what was wrong).